# aligning two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this block of html code. I like wuiLeftArea and wuiMainArea to stay side by side at all times. Right now, when shrink the brwoser window, WuiMainArea div is going below th wuileftArea. Is there a way to force the wuiMainArea div to stay on the right at all times?

```
<div id="wuiLeftArea">
        <div id="wuiLefthandNavRoot">
            <div id="tree">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<DIV id=wuiMainArea sizcache="5" sizset="1">
    <DIV id=wuiMainContent sizcache="5" sizset="1">
        <DIV id=wuiInpageNav sizcache="5" sizset="1">
              <DIV id=chart class=wui-inpage-container style="float:right; width: 1200px;min-height:500px;display: block; overflow: hidden;">
              <p > this is the area to put charts. this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                        this is the area to put charts. 
                </p>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will always happen unless there is a fixed size on the container or overflows are set explicitly; otherwise whenever any container is resized it will re-arrange its children to fit, width-wise, into its body.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XCEjf/

```
.wui-inpage-container {
    width: 50%;
}
```

By using a relative width you allow the float to always have room in the page width, preventing wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Use percentage-based lengths.  If the left container composes 25% width of the page and the maincontainer composes 75% width, then no matter how small the browser becomes you will have a 1/4 3/4 split